# Is there a way to shut off power to the HDMI output?

Tags: power, hdmi

I have a 5" display that runs entirely on the HDMI connection to the Pi, including power. Unfortunately, the display has a backlight which can't be switched off unless it is completely disconnected from power. Is there a way to shut off the power output to the HDMI port from the RPi OS?

I've tried commands like `tvservice -o` which was advised in other threads to shutoff HDMI displays. This indeed cuts the video feed to the HDMI output, but the power remains (apparently +5V on pin 18 is HDMI standard).

Answer (score 1):

No. The HDMI power is supplied via a RT9741CGV "High-Side Power Switch" and there seems to be no control.

Comment: thanks. Did you find that in the pi schematics somewhere?

Comment: @pinhead They were downloaded from the Foundation site. I don't have the link but the file name is RPI-3B-V1_2-SCHEMATIC-REDUCED.pdf

Comment: The link is (as of now) https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-3B-V1.2-Schematics.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Per Milliways answer, there's no built in method for cutting power to the HDMI socket. You could, if you were feeling keen, try using an [HDMI breakout board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3119) and either a relay or transistor connected to a GPIO pin to control the power to HDMI pin 18 on startup and shutdown.

Comment: You got me wondering if common HDMI switchers switch the power on the HDMI output.